# How to view/render autocad files (.dwg/.eps/.dwf) in android

Tags: android, autocad

Does anyone successfully render/view the autocad files(dwg/dwf/eps) in android? or any particular libraries out there? I just want to display it in android and be able to read the embedded gps location in that drawing, like it will match the current phone gps location to that location in the drawing and center the drawing's gps location relative to the phone screen. is it feasible? since autocad does not provide some sdk in mobiles?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an API on the horizon for mobile or at least web.
http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2014/07/my-first-autodesk-360-viewer-sample.html